# auto creating table on specific interval in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to create a table in oracle with name like ABC_DDMMYYYY. This table should be automatically created at the end of every month with that date.eg. for Sep the table should be created as ABC_30092014, for Oct it should be created as ABC_31102014.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This sounds like a really bad idea. Why not have a column that identifies the month in question. That will make queries like "give me all values in april and march" *much* easier.

Comment: In addition to @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion you should use a partitioned table with a partition for each month and the month column as partition key. I think this i a more common way than creating separate tables for each month.